# cannot view the output with echo

Tags: javascript, php, json, echo

```js
Array
(
    [id] => 9794ea5d-9dc1-4b15-a798-fd0fa4ff6f4c
    [timestamp] => 2017-07-05T03:47:00.764Z
    [lang] => en
    [result] => Array
        (
            [source] => agent
            [resolvedQuery] => what is annual leave
            [speech] => 
            [action] => test
            [actionIncomplete] => 
            [parameters] => Array
                (
                    [allowance_type] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [bonus_type] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [salary_type] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [leave_type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => annual leave
                        )

                )

            [contexts] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => to-apply
                            [parameters] => Array
                                (
                                    [allowance_type] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [leave_type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => annual leave
                                        )

                                    [bonus_type.original] => 
                                    [bonus_type] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [leave_type.original] => annual leave
                                    [allowance_type.original] => 
                                    [salary_type] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [salary_type.original] => 
                                )

                            [lifespan] => 5
                        )

                )

            [metadata] => Array
                (
                    [intentId] => e2bda510-2f4d-41b8-a80b-e11f148c804b
                    [webhookUsed] => true
                    [webhookForSlotFillingUsed] => false
                    [intentName] => description-definition-what
                )

            [fulfillment] => Array
                (
                    [speech] => 
                    [messages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 0
                                    [speech] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [score] => 1
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [errorType] => success
        )

    [sessionId] => 07a5acce-9587-4f06-b715-1c9106732109
)
```

Hi so i have this code where im trying to create a webhook to call the json file from API.AI. It gets the data and saves in a new file call JSON.php but im trying to echo out the data it is not happening. Is because the page is not auto refresh or?

```js
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
file_put_contents("JSON.php", print_r($data, true));

echo $data['intentName'];

?>
```

Comment: Try `print_r($data)` instead.

Comment: Are you sure that it's getting file, and if so, are you sure there is an element named 'intentName' that has a value to be displayed.

And I don't know what you mean by auto-refresh, that page isn't doing anything like that.

Comment: @Anon You should get rid of `['intentName']` because `intentName` maybe empty or doesn't exist , use  `print_r($data)` to print the whole array that decoded from that `json_decode`

Comment: Can use put your json output here?

Comment: why the file name is `json.php` it should be something like `*.json`. then you should decode the json.

Comment: @YamanJain i just named it json.php because its grabbing a json format from API.AI.. it can be anything .php or .txt or .json.. that is just to save the decoded json.. currently its getting the json from API.AI..

Answer (score 1):

So it should be `$data['result']['metadata']['intentName'];` instead of `$data['intentName']`

Comment: Sorry, its is `intentName` not `intendName`

Comment: yeah i noticed and tried that as well, still nothing

Comment: if its possible can you write the code your way and see if its works?